# PHP / AJAX: AJAX form doesn't remain at the same page after delete a data row

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Currently, I created search data by name and date range (from and to). I use AJAX to implement this. after I select name, date from, date to and press "search button", the data that I want to search is displayed. Each data that displays contain a delete button.

The button delete is run as well. But the problem is after I press the button delete at any data, the AJAX page will change to the normal page.

How do I want to make sure that after I pressed the delete button, the AJAX page will remain?

Below is my code

dashboard_engineer.php

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
         <div class='card bg-light'>
          <div class='card-body double'>
            <h4 class='card-title'>All Report</h4>
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td width="40%">
                  <select class="form-control"  name="team" id="team">
                    <option value="">Please select...</option>
                    <?php foreach ($data as $row2): ?>
                    <option value= <?php echo $row2["team_id"]; ?>><?php echo $row2["fullname"]; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                  </select>
                <td width="1%"></td>
                </td>
                <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="From" id="From" class="form-control" placeholder="From"></td>
                <td width="1%"></td>
                <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="form-control" placeholder="To"></td>
                <td width="1%"></td>
                <td width="10%"><input type="button" name="range" id="range" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary"><td>
              </tr>
            </table><br>
            <div id = "dashboard">
            <div class="row" style='height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;'>
              <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
                <?php

                $query = $conn->query("SELECT TOP 30 * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid WHERE ot_users.team_id <> 1  ORDER BY ot_report.report_date DESC");
                $query -> execute();
                $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                if($query->rowCount() == 0){

                  echo "<table class = 'table-bordered' width ='100%'>";
                  echo "<thead>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th width = '5%'>id</th>
                        <th width = '12%'>Date</th>
                        <th width = '29%'>Officer/ Asst. Engineer</th>
                        <th width = '23%'>Task Name</th>
                        <th width = '7%'>From</th>
                        <th width = '7%'>To</th>
                        <th width = '10%'>Status</th>
                        <th width = '7%'>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody >
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan='8'>No report at this moment</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>";
                }else{

                      echo "<table class = 'table-bordered' width ='100%'>";
                      echo "<thead>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<th width = '5%'>id</th>
                            <th width = '12%'>Date</th>
                            <th width = '29%'>Officer/ Asst. Engineer</th>
                            <th width = '23%'>Task Name</th>
                            <th width = '7%'>From</th>
                            <th width = '7%'>To</th>
                            <th width = '10%'>Status</th>
                            <th width = '7%'>Action</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody >";

                        $query = $conn->query("SELECT TOP 30 * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid WHERE ot_users.team_id <> 1  ORDER BY ot_report.report_date DESC");
                        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        $status=$row['report_status'];
                        if($status=="Pending")
                        {
                          $color="color:blue";
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            $color="color:green";
                        }

                        echo "<tr>";

                          $datereport = $row['report_date'];
                          $datereport2 = strtotime($datereport);
                          $report_date = date('d M Y', $datereport2);

                          $start = $row['ot_start'];
                          $start2 = strtotime($row['ot_start']);
                          $ot_start = date('H:i', $start2);

                          $end = $row['ot_end'];
                          $end2 = strtotime($end);
                          $ot_end = date('H:i', $end2);

                          echo "<td>". $row['report_id']. "</td>";
                          echo "<td>". $report_date . "</td>";
                          echo "<td>". $row['fullname'] . "</td>";
                          echo "<td>". $row['task_name'] . "</td>";

                          if ($row['ot_start'] == '00:00:00'){
                            echo "<td align='center'>-</td>";
                          }else{
                            echo "<td align='center'>".$ot_start. "</td>";
                          }

                          if ($row['ot_end'] == '00:00:00'){
                            echo "<td align='center'>-</td>";
                          }else{
                            echo "<td align='center'>".$ot_end. "</strong></td>";
                          }

                          echo "<td align='center' style='$color'><strong>". $status . "</strong></td>";
                          echo "<td align='center'>";
                            echo "<a class='btn-view btn-primary btn-sm' href='view_task/view_task.php?report_id=". $row['report_id'] ."' data-toggle='tooltip'>View</a>";
                            echo "<a class='btn-view btn-danger btn-sm' href=\"delete.php?report_id=$row[report_id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Do you want to remove team?')\">Remove</a></td>";
                            echo "</td>";

                        echo "</tr>";
                        }

                        echo "</tbody>";
                      echo "</table><br>";  
                }
                ?> 
                </div>

  <!-- AJAX Date Range -->

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    $(function(){
      $("#From").datepicker().attr("autocomplete", "off");;
      $("#to").datepicker().attr("autocomplete", "off");;
    });
    $('#range').click(function(){
      var From = $('#From').val();
      var to = $('#to').val();
      var team = $('#team').val();
      if(From != '' && to != '' && team != '')
      {
        $.ajax({
          url:"range.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{From:From, to:to, team:team},
          success:function(data)
          {
            $('#dashboard').html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      else
      {
        alert("Please select both team and date range");
      }
    });
  });
  </script>

  <!-- AJAX Date Range END-->
```

delete.php

```
    <?php

    //including the database connection file
    require_once '../../../config/configPDO.php';

    //getting id of the data from url
    $report_id = $_GET['report_id'];


    $sql = "DELETE FROM ot_report WHERE report_id=:report_id";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));

    //redirecting to the display page (index.php in our case)
    header("Location: dashboard_engineer.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: Use don't use AJAX for delete the product, so the page change by delete.php.

Comment: then? what should i do?

Comment: you can use an value $_GET to delete page, so when you click and return to AJAX page you will display same data user insert. and when ajax page is loading use script jquery/js onload to active ajax with $_get propriety.

Comment: Use ajax API call to delete the product once product deleted you can refresh the data using list API Call

Comment: @SimoneRossaini can you help me to edit my code above. Pleaseeee

Comment: @dhamo can you give the example base on my code above?

Comment: What do you mean by "the AJAX page will change to the normal page"? What have you tried to debug this problem?

Comment: It is hard to tell because there is so much code here (please in future try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but it looks like you are just missing [`.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), to stop the standard form submission happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using ajax to delete row, you are using default anchor tag 
which redirects you to another page, if you want to implement ajax you should do something like this:

Add a class and data atribute to delete anchor:

```
// delete-row class added
echo "<a class='btn-view btn-danger btn-sm delete-row' data-report-id='<?php echo $row[report_id] ?>' href=\"delete.php?report_id=$row[report_id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Do you want to remove team?')\">Remove</a></td>";
```

Add click event listener to that class:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function(e) {
  // prevents a tag from redirecting to another page
  e.preventDefault();

  // id of selected row
  let rowId = $(this).data('report-id');

  // validate row id here if you want
  ...

  // trigger ajax to delete.php
$.ajax({
    url: '/pathto/delete.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {report_id: rowId },
    success: function( response ) {
        response = JSON.parse( response );

        // delete row html if response is successful, otherwise display an error
        if (response.status == 'success') {
            // remove html here
        } else {
            // append error message here
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log( xhr.responseText );
    }
});
});
```

Finally,update you delete.php to be like this:

```
<?php

    //including the database connection file
    require_once '../../../config/configPDO.php';

    //getting id of the data from url
    $report_id = $_GET['report_id'];


    $sql = "DELETE FROM ot_report WHERE report_id=:report_id";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if($query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id))) {
         echo json_encode([
            'status' => 'success',
         ]);
    } else {
         echo json_encode([
            'status' => 'error',
         ]);
    } 

    exit();
    ?>
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific

Comment: echo "<a class='btn-view btn-danger btn-sm delete-row' data-report-id="<?php echo $row[report_id] ?>" href=\"delete.php?report_id=$row[report_id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Do you want to remove team?')\">Remove</a></td>";

Comment: ah I used "" instead of ´´ for data-report-id="<?php echo $row[report_id] ?>", just change it to data-report-id='<?php echo $row[report_id] ?>'

Comment: after I delete o item, it will display message : {"status":"success"}. when i click back, it will return to the normal page, not the ajax page